# Getting Value and Storing data through CK Editor

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, liferay

In a form I have a field called `Description`. Through CKEditor I need to pass that value and store it in my database. Can anyone help me out? Here is my code:

```html
<div id="descriptionMore" style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-top: 38px;margin-left: 101px;">
    <aui:layout>
        <aui:column columnWidth="240">
            <liferay-ui:input-editor width="880" cssClass="richText" />
        </aui:column>
    </aui:layout>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are using **aui:form**.

Link which will be useful for you.

- [Save Content of CKeditor via "aui:form"](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/37149115)
- [Add HTML Editor to Portlet](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Add+HTML+Editor+to+Portlet)
- [CK editor in Liferay 6.0](http://kamalkantrajput.blogspot.in/2011/03/ck-editor-in-liferay-60.html)
- [Adding CK Editor in Liferay](http://liferaytutorial.blogspot.in/2013/11/adding-ck-editor-in-liferay.html)

This will defiantly be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%
    Content content = (Content) request.getAttribute(ApplicationConstants.CONTENT);      
    %>
  <portlet:actionURL var="saveOrUpdateContentUrl" name="saveOrUpdateContent">
        <portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%=currentURL%>" />
    </portlet:actionURL>
    <liferay-ui:header title='<%= (content==null) ? "new-content" : "edit-content"  %>' backURL="<%=redirect %>" />

    <aui:form method="post" name="content_fm" onSubmit='<%= "event.preventDefault(); " + renderResponse.getNamespace() + "saveEntry();" %>'>
        <aui:fieldset>
            <aui:field-wrapper label="product-content">
                <liferay-ui:input-editor />
                <aui:input name="content" id="content" type="hidden" />
            </aui:field-wrapper>

            <aui:button-row>
                <aui:button type="submit" />
            </aui:button-row>

        </aui:fieldset>
    </aui:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function <portlet:namespace />initEditor() {
            return '<%= UnicodeFormatter.toString((content==null)? StringPool.BLANK : content.getContent()) %>';
        }
        function <portlet:namespace />getContent() {
            return window.<portlet:namespace />editor.getHTML();
        }
        function <portlet:namespace />saveEntry() {
            document.<portlet:namespace />content_fm.action = '<%=saveOrUpdateContentUrl%>';
            document.<portlet:namespace />content_fm.<portlet:namespace />content.value = <portlet:namespace />getContent();
            alert(<portlet:namespace />getContent());
            submitForm(document.<portlet:namespace />content_fm);
        }
    </script>
```

This above code is properly working in Liferay 6.2. You should fetch CKEditor content using alloy script or javascript and set in hidden parameter for storing the value.